# Entering a usable numerical array in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I want to enter an array of numbers to perform their addition in python 2.7 sort of which it would look like

```
"for (i=1;i<=n,i++)

scanf("%d", &a[i])"
```

in C

How do I do this?

I am a new to programming altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Copy of your code in Python:

```
a = [None] * n
for i in xrange(1,n+1,1):
    a[i-1] = int(input())
```

But more Pythonic way would be:

```
a = []
for i in xrange(n):
    a.append(int(input()))
```

or even shorter(but i wouldn't recommend it until you know more about python):

```
a = [int(input()) for i in xrange(n)]
```

If you are new to this language it is better to start with Python 3.6 instead of 2.7.

Also i recomend getting to know more about python reading nicely written guide on offical site https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/.

Part about [for loops and range](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function) and  [input/output](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html)